# How do I lay out the start point of path elements along a half-circle in SVG?

Tags: svg

I have an svg that I've generated via some Javascript.  I'm fine with that code, but what I'd like to do is place each path along the arc of a half circle (of a radius of 24 in this example) rather than the center path (the "marker" id). I'm not sure how you do that -- I know you'd need to indicate the starting point for each element of the arc at M, but I'm not sure how to calculate the offset to make sure they lay out along that arc, whether in Javascript or just abstractly so I can generate code based off of it. I've included the full code of the svg I have currently so far, and I apologize if anyone feels it's too long.

```html
    <svg width="100%" viewBox="0 0 160 110">
        <path id="a6" d="M 80 100 C 60 95, 40 100, 10 100, -20 100" stroke="#CCCCCC"
            stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></path>
        <path id="b6" d="M 80 99.5 C 60 92, 40 97, 10 97.25, -20 97" stroke="#EEFFFF"
            stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></path>
        <path id="c6" d="M 80 99 C 60 89, 40 94, 10 94.5, -20 94" stroke="#CCCCCC"
            stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></path>
        <path id="d6" d="M 80 98.5 C 60 86, 40 91, 10 91.75, -20 91" stroke="#EEFFFF"
            stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></path>
        <path id="e6" d="M 80 98 C 60 83, 40 88, 10 89, -20 88" stroke="#CCCCCC"
            stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></path>
        <path id="f6" d="M 80 97.5 C 60 80, 40 85, 10 86.25, -20 85" stroke="#EEFFFF"
            stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></path>
        <path id="g6" d="M 80 97 C 60 77, 40 82, 10 83.5, -20 82" stroke="#CCCCCC"
            stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></path>
        <path id="h6" d="M 80 96.5 C 60 74, 40 79, 10 80.75, -20 79" stroke="#EEFFFF"
            stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></path>
        <path id="i6" d="M 80 96 C 60 71, 40 76, 10 78, -20 76" stroke="#CCCCCC"
            stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></path>
        <path id="k6" d="M 80 95.5 C 60 68, 40 73, 10 75.25, -20 73" stroke="#EEFFFF"
            stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></path>
        <path id="l6" d="M 80 95 C 60 65, 40 70, 10 72.5, -20 70" stroke="#CCCCCC"
            stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></path>
        <path id="m6" d="M 80 94.5 C 60 62, 40 67, 10 69.75, -20 67" stroke="#EEFFFF"
            stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></path>
        <path id="n6" d="M 80 94 C 60 59, 40 64, 10 67, -20 64" stroke="#CCCCCC"
            stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></path>
        <path id="o6" d="M 80 93.5 C 60 56, 40 61, 10 64.25, -20 61" stroke="#EEFFFF"
            stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></path>
        <path id="p6" d="M 80 93 C 60 53, 40 58, 10 61.5, -20 58" stroke="#CCCCCC"
            stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></path>
        <path id="q6" d="M 80 92.5 C 60 50, 40 55, 10 58.75, -20 55" stroke="#EEFFFF"
            stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></path>
        <path id="r6" d="M 80 92 C 60 47, 40 52, 10 56, -20 52" stroke="#CCCCCC"
            stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></path>
        <path id="s6" d="M 80 91.5 C 60 44, 40 49, 10 53.25, -20 49" stroke="#EEFFFF"
            stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></path>
        <path id="t6" d="M 80 91 C 60 41, 40 46, 10 50.5, -20 46" stroke="#CCCCCC"
            stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></path>
        <path id="v6" d="M 80 90.5 C 60 38, 40 43, 10 47.75, -20 43" stroke="#EEFFFF"
            stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></path>
        <path id="x6" d="M 80 90 C 60 35, 40 40, 10 45, -20 40" stroke="#CCCCCC"
            stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></path>
        <path id="y6" d="M 80 89.5 C 60 32, 40 37, 10 42.25, -20 37" stroke="#EEFFFF"
            stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></path>
        <path id="z6" d="M 80 89 C 60 29, 40 34, 10 39.5, -20 34" stroke="#CCCCCC"
            stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></path>
        <path id="aa6" d="M 80 88.5 C 60 26, 40 31, 10 36.75, -20 31" stroke="#EEFFFF"
            stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></path>
        <path id="bb6" d="M 80 88 C 60 23, 40 28, 10 34, -20 28" stroke="#CCCCCC"
            stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></path>
        <path id="cc6" d="M 80 87.5 C 60 20, 40 25, 10 31.25, -20 25" stroke="#EEFFFF"
            stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></path>
        <path id="dd6" d="M 80 87 C 60 17, 40 22, 10 28.5, -20 22" stroke="#CCCCCC"
            stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></path>
        <path id="ee6" d="M 80 86.5 C 60 14, 40 19, 10 25.75, -20 19" stroke="#EEFFFF"
            stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></path>
        <path id="ff6" d="M 80 86 C 60 11, 40 16, 10 23, -20 16" stroke="#CCCCCC"
            stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></path>
        <path id="gg6" d="M 80 85.5 C 60 8, 40 13, 10 20.25, -20 13" stroke="#EEFFFF"
            stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></path>
        <path id="hh6" d="M 80 100 C 100 95, 120 100, 150 100, 180 100" stroke="#CCCCCC"
            stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></path>
        <path id="ii6" d="M 80 99.5 C 100 92, 120 97, 150 97.25, 180 97" stroke="#EEFFFF"
            stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></path>
        <path id="kk6" d="M 80 99 C 100 89, 120 94, 150 94.5, 180 94" stroke="#CCCCCC"
            stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></path>
        <path id="ll6" d="M 80 98.5 C 100 86, 120 91, 150 91.75, 180 91" stroke="#EEFFFF"
            stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></path>
        <path id="mm6" d="M 80 98 C 100 83, 120 88, 150 89, 180 88" stroke="#CCCCCC"
            stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></path>
        <path id="nn6" d="M 80 97.5 C 100 80, 120 85, 150 86.25, 180 85" stroke="#EEFFFF"
            stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></path>
        <path id="oo6" d="M 80 97 C 100 77, 120 82, 150 83.5, 180 82" stroke="#CCCCCC"
            stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></path>
        <path id="pp6" d="M 80 96.5 C 100 74, 120 79, 150 80.75, 180 79" stroke="#EEFFFF"
            stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></path>
        <path id="qq6" d="M 80 96 C 100 71, 120 76, 150 78, 180 76" stroke="#CCCCCC"
            stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></path>
        <path id="rr6" d="M 80 95.5 C 100 68, 120 73, 150 75.25, 180 73" stroke="#EEFFFF"
            stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></path>
        <path id="ss6" d="M 80 95 C 100 65, 120 70, 150 72.5, 180 70" stroke="#CCCCCC"
            stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></path>
        <path id="tt6" d="M 80 94.5 C 100 62, 120 67, 150 69.75, 180 67" stroke="#EEFFFF"
            stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></path>
        <path id="vv6" d="M 80 94 C 100 59, 120 64, 150 67, 180 64" stroke="#CCCCCC"
            stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></path>
        <path id="xx6" d="M 80 93.5 C 100 56, 120 61, 150 64.25, 180 61" stroke="#EEFFFF"
            stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></path>
        <path id="yy6" d="M 80 93 C 100 53, 120 58, 150 61.5, 180 58" stroke="#CCCCCC"
            stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></path>
        <path id="zz6" d="M 80 92.5 C 100 50, 120 55, 150 58.75, 180 55" stroke="#EEFFFF"
            stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></path>
        <path id="aaa6" d="M 80 92 C 100 47, 120 52, 150 56, 180 52" stroke="#CCCCCC"
            stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></path>
        <path id="bbb6" d="M 80 91.5 C 100 44, 120 49, 150 53.25, 180 49" stroke="#EEFFFF"
            stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></path>
        <path id="marker" d="M 80 100 C 80 85.5, 80 85.5, 80 85.5, 80 85.5" stroke="#EEFFFF"
            stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></path>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Does it need to be segmented? Also, rather than computing the arc locations, another option is to use transforms.

Comment: You can use the javascript method [getPointAtLength()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGeometryElement/getPointAtLength) which is returning the point at a given distance along the path. Also since you are using a circle as starting point you can calculate the position of a point at a given angle with this formulas: `x = center.x + radius * Math.cos(angle); y = center.y + radius * Math.sin(angle);`